# Mass Effect 2: New Game Plus

Tags: mass-effect-2

After finishing the story of Mass Effect 2, we get the choice to continue to complete the different/unfinished missions throughout the game or to import our character and play through a new game at our current saved level and power stats. I have noticed that I do not level up at all during my new playthrough. I gain Paragon/Renegade points to help me with conversations but not at any stage have I leveled up. My powers and all characters no longer level up and gain power points. I only ask because I was able to play playthrough after playthrough in Mass Effect 1 and continued to level up; this is not happening in Mass Effect 2. If you know the answer, is that the way it is when you import your ME2 character after a playthrough or is my game/system messed up?

Thank you to anyone who can help me with this. I have searched elsewhere but have found no answers at all.

Comment: Have you reached the max level already (30)?

Comment: What exactly is a "munter" ?

Comment: Max level for Mass Effect 1 was 60, which made it more likely that you still had levels to go when starting over.

Comment: @gnomeslice: The only thing I know of is a melee-specced hunter in WoW. Term usually used with derision.

Answer (score 14):

In ME1, the level cap for the first playthrough was 50, once you finished a playthrough it was bumped to 60 for all subsequent playthroughs.

ME2 doesn't increase the level cap, once you hit 30 you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The level cap is fixed at 30 for all playthroughs in ME2. From the [ME2 wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_2#Advancement):

> The new level cap is 30. Further advancing powers no longer is a
>   simple point per power advancement system. Powers now cost an
>   increasing number of points to advance and offer a specialization
>   choice when maxed out. Since you can only max out five powers, this
>   greatly affects play style of the characters. As such it is now
>   possible to reset your advancement and reset your character in-game.
>   However, your main character can gain new powers throughout the game,
>   and unique powers can be unlocked for team mates through game play.
>
> As was in Mass Effect, all party members gain experience and level up
>   simultaneously regardless of their participation in missions or
>   if/when they are recruited. Each time the party levels up, Shepard is
>   awarded two additional squad points to spend on skill development.
>   Other party members receive two squad points at each new level from
>   levels 1 to 5 and two points every two levels from level 5 to 19.
>   After level 19 party members receive only one squad point every two
>   levels.